# Does Renewing SSL certificate change its thumbprint / Fingerprint

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-pinning

I would like to know, if renewing a SSL certificate will change my thumbprint? The certificate has expired.

If it can be same then under what conditions can it remain same.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of certificate pinning do you use?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what fingerprint you mean.

- The public key fingerprint is a hash of the public key only. Since the public key stays the same on a simple renewing, this fingerprint will be the same too.
- The certificate fingerprint as shown in the browser is instead a hash of the complete certificate. Since the contents of the certificate will change to reflect the new start and expiration time, this fingerprint will change too.

Answer (score 3):

Fingerprint for Public Key Pinning stays the same if you renew the cert with the same private key you used before. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning#Extracting_the_Base64_encoded_public_key_information) for instructions how to generate the fingerprint, you can see it can be extracted from private key or CSR, not only from the cert itself.